# AppCompat CardView shadow padding on API < 21 doesn't fit specifications

Tags: android, padding, android-appcompat, android-cardview

I am using CardView in a RecyclerView like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground">
```

According to the android API docs the padding is supposed to be

```
maxCardElevation * 1.5 + (1 - cos45) * cornerRadius
```

When I System.out.print the maxElevation it is 4.0 which leads to a padding of ~7.17. However when I turn on the LayoutBounds it is easy to see the padding is actually not even 2 dp.

I am trying to fix my cardspacing in the list but without knowing the real padding this isn't possible.

Does anyone have any insight on this matter?

Edit: I'm running it on a Nexus 4 with CyanogenMod11 M11

Comment: In pixels on xxhdpi, that's about right.

Comment: You're right I just assumed the documentation meant dynamic pixels. Maybe that isn't true. What is the best way to counteract this padding to achieve the correct spacing according to the material guidelines?